# Getting "WS Security Header in the message is invalid." when calling ACAGetTransmitterBulkRequestStatus

Tags: web-services, soap, ws-security, xml-signature, irs

I've been able to make successfull call to first ACA web service and I thought, that getting status would be a breeze. Bo-o-oy how I have been wrong!

I've used same settings for the status service as I did for the submit one... and I got "WS Security header is invalid error!" What gives?!?! Signature generation code is the same as I been using for submission! I would appreciate if any one would be able shed some light what possibly is wrong here?
I am aware, that following tags should be digitally signed(and I do signed them):

1. ACABusinessHeader
2. ACABulkRequestTransmitterStatusDetailRequest
3. Security timestamp

Here is my Request:

```
POST https://la.www4.irs.gov/airp/aca/a2a/1095BC_Status_Request_AATS2016 HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: "RequestSubmissionStatusDetail"
Host: la.www4.irs.gov
Content-Length: 5217
Expect: 100-continue
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive

<s:Envelope xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Header>
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
        <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <SignedInfo>
                <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#WithComments" />
                <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
                <Reference URI="#_1">
                    <Transforms>
                        <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                    </Transforms>
                    <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
                    <DigestValue>KBLc15A=</DigestValue>
                </Reference>
                <Reference URI="#_2">
                    <Transforms>
                        <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                    </Transforms>
                    <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
                    <DigestValue>dhkLQhzfkc=</DigestValue>
                </Reference>
                <Reference URI="#TS-ccf5abbbd36940f693d56b21ab489674">
                    <Transforms>
                        <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                    </Transforms>
                    <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
                    <DigestValue>O179zVlJnyo=</DigestValue>
                </Reference>
            </SignedInfo>
            <SignatureValue>REDUCTED</SignatureValue>
            <KeyInfo>
                <wsse:SecurityTokenReference xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
                    <wsse:KeyIdentifier ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">-- Base64ed cert ---</wsse:KeyIdentifier>
                </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
            </KeyInfo>
        </Signature>
        <u:Timestamp u:Id="TS-ccf5abbbd36940f693d56b21ab489674">
            <u:Created>2016-04-01T15:02:00.505Z</u:Created>
            <u:Expires>2016-04-01T15:12:00.506Z</u:Expires>
        </u:Timestamp>
    </wsse:Security>
    <abh:ACABusinessHeader u:Id="_1" xmlns:abh="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:msg:acabusinessheader">
        <UniqueTransmissionId xmlns="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:ext:aca:air:7.0">REDUCTED</UniqueTransmissionId>
        <Timestamp xmlns="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:common">2016-04-01T11:02:58Z</Timestamp>
    </abh:ACABusinessHeader>
</s:Header>
<s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <ACABulkRequestTransmitterStatusDetailRequest u:Id="_2" version="1.0" xmlns="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:msg:irstransmitterstatusrequest">
        <ACABulkReqTrnsmtStsReqGrpDtl xmlns="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:ext:aca:air:7.0">
            <ReceiptId xmlns="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:common">Receit Id</ReceiptId>
        </ACABulkReqTrnsmtStsReqGrpDtl>
    </ACABulkRequestTransmitterStatusDetailRequest>
</s:Body>
```

**UPDATE1:** I am more and more convinced, that something is up on their end with our certificate and status service. It looks like they unable to map receipt id to the proper certificate. At least they conformed, that structurally there is nothing wrong with the XML, that I've been sending them. But they unable to identify the actual problem. IRS asked me to resent them my request in the email again for farther investigation, which I did. Now will wait and c what will happen.

Comment: How are you generating the xml? I've only been able to get my solution working with the IRS by manually creating my SOAP envelope and headers manually, excepting the Security element largely being generated by the SignedXml class.

Comment: @Bon Thank you for responding!I am manually generating signature using SignedXml class. So I think in that department we are in the same boat. What I don't understand why what's working for submit service is not working for status one? I saw you made it working for both services, what was the difference, that made status service work?

Comment: I think the only difference for me was signing the different elements as specified in their pdf.

Comment: @Bon Thank you for the replay. I see. I was thinking, that service expecting different algorithms for signature generation. Obviously it's not the case. As a straw grasp: would it be possible for you to share how successful request is look like?

Comment: @Bon You are passing in the KeyIdentifier field certificate, which has been loaded on IRS site, right?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, long story short. Status service is working now. After all back'n'forthing IRS development team removed client configurations, which where marked as deleted and after that, seems, status service got itself a spirit to work. I am a bit weary about how situation has been resolved, but if it eventually started to work - let it be!

Answer (score 0):

(I don't have enough reputation to add a comment)

@fatherOfWine, I noticed that the InclusiveNamespaces element is missing in your Transform elements. Sorry for stating something that you might already know, the included namespaces are factored in in the canonicalization of the XML and eventually the calculation of the SHA1 digests.

Send an email to IRS' ACA Technical Support and ask them to look at their logs if the three digest values you send are passing or matching their calculations. They'll be able to at least identify which of your digest values are passing and failing their checks. Let them know the TCC and local time you sent the request.

Comment: Thank u for your response.  But AFAIK inclusive namespaces are necessary only if their definitions are external to the document being signed. That aside my submit service works quite well and it uses same signing code, which produced signature for the request I've placed in this question. What is good for the goose should be good for the gander, n'es pas?:))